# Manage discriminator properly in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, discriminator, ef-core-5.0

I have one entity were I describe Document Type :

```
public class DocumentType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsLogical { get; set; }
}
```

You can see the boolean IsLogical. If it set to true, It means it's a document which point to a list of DocumentType where IsLogical is set to false (physical document). The objective is to declare a document like "Identity document" and point it to "Id Card" and "Passport" and "Driving licence" for example.

I don't find to good way to do it. I found three different ways but I'm not confortable with :

- Declare another entity

I can declare another entity like "LogicalToPhysical" with only foreign keys but I don't know if EF Core can manage something like this : LogicalDocumentTypeId is an Id from DocumentType (FK) where IsLogical is set to true and PhysicalDocumentTypeId is an Id from DocumentType (another FK) where IsLogical is set to false (one to many relationship).

- Using Inherance

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), I can use inherance but I don't know how set the other entity in order to manage my one to many relationship. Another problem is to manage two kind of objects.

- Using value Object / Owned Entity types

If I understood properly this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), I can using Value object in order to map my list, but I'm not sure how do this.

Maybe my conception is very bad, but if I can avoid to manage differents objects (and query from different sources), it would be better.

I'm using Entity Framework Core 5 in a net core API project with SQL Server 2019.

EDIT : in my reasoning, I imagine something like that :

Example of DocumentType

```
{1, 'Toto', 'blabla', false }
{2, 'Titi', 'blabla', false }
{3, 'Tutu', 'blabla', true }
{4, 'Tata', 'blabla', false }
```

Id 3 --> IsLogical : true

Example of another table (LogicalDocument for example)

```
LogicalDocument {DocumentType.Id FK, DocumentType.Id FK)
{ 3, 1 } // Tutu is pointing to Toto
{ 3, 2 } // Tutu is pointing to Titi
```

Comment: From your description, it seems that  you want to add some properties according to the IsLogical property, right? If that is the case, can you tell us what the table look like if IsLogical is `true` and `false`, and it is better to add some test data and create a simple sample, then, we can according to it to give a suitable solution.

Comment: I tried to give an example. I don't know if it illustrate properly my meaning

Comment: Why you dont use Json with a convension? You can keep the list in json column and you can write a convension if you use mssql. If you are using another databases, may be they already support json. So in single json column you can keep them. https://github.com/iozcelik/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.JsonExtention This is little old but it gives an idea to you.